# Ouroboros – Which version is currently implemented?

Tags: ouroboros

I was reading this blog post [From Classic to Hydra](https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2020/03/23/from-classic-to-hydra-the-implementations-of-ouroboros-explained/) and I was wondering which version of Ouroboros is currently implemented in Cardano: Classic, BFT or Praos?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updated: July 20, 2023.

### Ouroboros family implementations

- **Classic**    *implemented in 2017*
- **BFT**        *implemented*
- **Praos**      *is* ***currently running***
- **Genesis**    (*development's in progress...*)
- **Hydra**      (*development's in progress...*)
- **Crypsinous** (*development’s in progress...*)
- **Chronos**    (*development’s in progress...*)
- **Leios**      (*development’s in progress...*)
- **Omega**      (*brings together Classic, Praos, Genesis, Redux, Chronos, etc...*)

***Details you can find in my medium story [Twenty interesting facts about Cardano](https://medium.com/geekculture/cardano-911-twenty-interesting-facts-about-cardano-6e165914d1e8)***.

### Eras

Some of the above algorithms have mutually dependent ingredients for launching a certain era:

- **Byron Era** (Foundation) – *reached in 2017*
- **Shelley Era** (Decentralization and delegation) – *reached in 2020*

  - **Allegra Sub-Era** (Token locking mechanism)
  - **Mary Sub-Era** (Multi-asset implementation)
- **Goguen Era** (Smart Contracts, DeFi, Dapps) – *hit Testnet in September 2021*

  - **Alonzo Sub-Era** (Smart Contracts implementation)
  - **Babbage Sub-Era** (Eliminates flaws of Alonzo)
  - **Vasil Sub-Era** (Increases network's scaling capabilities) – *reached in July 2022*
- **Basho Era** (Scalability and Interoperability) – *be ready for it in 2023*
- **Voltaire Era** (Governance) – *development's in progress...*

Comment: And Omega is in planned state as far as I know. If everything is OK next year should be implemented.

Comment: Thanx a lot @PetarEnchev, I've inserted it.

Comment: Very clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: What about [Ouroboros Chronos](https://iohk.io/en/research/library/papers/ouroboros-chronospermissionless-clock-synchronization-via-proof-of-stake/) and [Ouroboros Crypsinous](https://iohk.io/en/research/library/papers/ouroboros-crypsinousprivacy-preserving-proof-of-stake/)?

Comment: Ouroboros Chronos has been available since 2019: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/838

Comment: According to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/IOHK_Charles/status/1357364560504709120/photo/2) Ouroboros Chronos should be part of Omega.

Comment: Thanks a lot @user142, I've included both in the list.

Comment: still Praos? was genesis published in 2018?

Comment: Hey @Rong, as far as I know [Ouroboros Genesis](https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2023/02/09/ouroboros-genesis-enhanced-security-in-a-dynamic-environment/) will be deployed in January 2024.